# Change color of question hyperlink in "Edit post" page in Dark Mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, dark-mode

In the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34949611/edit) page of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936397/verify-path-traversal-vulnerability-in-web-server) question, I thought the page was missing the hyperlink to the question, because the color is so dark:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Upon searching, I found that the color is `#000 !important`.  Can we change that to `var(--blue-600)`, so it looks:

[image]

Like this?

<sup>You may have to try it yourself to get it right; it doesn't look so sharp in the screenshots.</sup>

Comment: This link appears when editing answers in a new tab (by opening the edit link in a new tab or by having less than 2000 reputation points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this has merged and will deploy soon. There is plenty in the queue after the American Thanksgiving holiday last week. Sit tight. Thanks for pointing it out!